# converting float to sprintf

Tags: c

I'm trying to convert a float to char string I used sprintf, as the following

```
         float temperature = getTemperature();

         char array[15];
         sprintf(array, "temperature %f", temperature);

         int length = strlen(array);
         protocol_WriteMessage(length,(unsigned char*)&array);
```

but protocol_WriteMessage accepts unsigned char *, so I casted it, but the program crashes.

```
void protocol_WriteMessage( UINT16 wLen, UINT8 *pbData )
{
    UINT16 crc_calc;

    // Calculate transmitt CRC16
    crc_calc = calc_crc16(&pbData[COMM_POS_COMMAND1], wLen-COMM_POS_COMMAND1);

    comm_states.TxActive    = true;          // signal that the Tx_UART is working

    // write data without further checks
    hal_uart_WriteBuffer( wLen, pbData );
}
```

Comment: Don't you think `15` is a bit too short?

Comment: Can someone make a bad pun about the comment above?, And yes, you need a bigger array

Comment: Hey, a good one please!

Comment: @Andre when passing a string to your function just send the pointer like protocol_WriteMessage(length,(unsigned char*)array);

Comment: Could simplify to `unsigned char array[11 + 1 + 50]; protocol_WriteMessage(snprintf(array, sizeof array, "temperature %f", getTemperature()),array);`

Comment: the use of `COMM_POS_COMMAND1` suggests you were supposed to put a command header in the buffer before calling `protocol_WriteMessage`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all use a safer alternative like [`snprintf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html), and then remove the `&` address of operator from the call.

To use `snprintf()` you need to do something like this

```
int result;
char array[32]; // This should be big enough

result = snprintf(array, sizeof(array), "temperature %f", temperature);
if ((result == -1) || (result >= sizeof(array))) {
    // It means that array is too small, or some other error
    // occurred such that `snprintf' has returned -1
}

protocol_WriteMessage(length, (unsigned char *) array);
```

since array is already a pointer to the first element of itself, which is of type `char` then it's type is `char *` when passed like that as a pointer, using the `&` operator is clearly wrong and casting only hides the fact that you made a mistake.

Comment: Disagree with "safer alternative like snprintf()" and not showing how to use it.  By using `snprintf(array, sizeof array, ...)` and not checking the result, OP is simply truncating the ideal result of `"temperature 25.000000"` to `"temperature 25"`.  With `temperature = 125`, result is `"temperature 12"` which is wrong, but not obviously wrong as it is the same result of `temperature = 12`. (So embedded controller says, keep heating, its too cold!)  I see lawsuit in the future.

Comment: This is a good example of why suggesting `snprintf()` without detailing how to use it is a poor answer.  Alternatively code could have used a larger buffer and `sprintf()` and not incurred this problem, albeit other problems.  Recommend detailing proper use of `snprintf()` as that function have a fundamental weakness - it can generates partial string results .

Comment: @chux I added a link to the documentation so the OP can read it. The question is not about `snprintf()` I'ts just an improvement on the original code that I thougt good to suggest.

Comment: OP's problem was certainly UB caused by using too small a buffer (`"temperature %f"` would need _at least_ `[21]`) and the  `snprintf()` fix suggested here remedied that overflow - but in a potentially dangerous way.  The `&` issue was a minor point.

Comment: The return type of `snprintf` is `int` ... storing this in `ssize_t` gives the illusion of safety in some cases